# Viewing heap content in gdb

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, heap-memory

I have a compiled 64 bit elf for a c program with two pointers with size 16 bytes each on the heap(with fast bin). I want to view their content in gdb for debugging purposes, but I dont have any debug symbols. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is exceedingly unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the pointers should be on the stack and you could access them using gdb view stack frame command `x/<#num>x $sp` where #num is the number of stack elements to view.

And from there you can get the addresses that the pointers point to in the heap.